# reactor-core thread hanging when used with <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux 2.4.5. works fine with 2.3.4.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I've been using spring webclient to call multiple asynchrounous post calls to a rest a API. It seemed to work fine until I tried to update to `spring-boot-starter-webflux 2.4.5` from `2.3.4.RELEASE`. After I upgrade the thread seems to hang and I traced it down to
`int r = tryAcquireShared(arg);` in `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` class where the 'r' value is being set to -1 and then nothing happens after that. Any idea what could be happening?

````
        ...

        return webClient.post()
                .uri(apiPath)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, getUserAgent())
                .body(Mono.just(new DetailsImpl.Builder().serial(requestDetail.getSerial()).build()), Details.class)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.class,
                        ex -> {
                        
                            return Mono.just(requestDetail.getSerial() + ex.getStatusCode());
                        });
    }

    public Response getDetails(final Request request) throws Exception {
        logger.debug("request: " + request);
        List<Details> DetailsList = request.getDetails();

        Flux<String> flx = Flux.fromIterable(DetailsList)
                .parallel()
                .runOn(Schedulers.elastic())
                .flatMap(this::getDetail).sequential();

        List<String> allRawResults = Flux.merge(flx).collectList().block();

        Response response = processResponse(allRawResults);

        logger.debug("response: " + response.getResponseMap());

        return response;
    }```
````

Comment: could you provide a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: Could you please help advise what was the issue and what fix was applied?